# Book about a boy and a girl from opposite sides of a magical forest

Tags: story-identification, books

Book about young girl from one side of magical forest, and boy is from wizards on the other side of magical forest and they don't get along. The boy should have magic, but his hasn't come in yet, and his brother always teases him. He also has magic creatures that are his group, and the boy and girl end up meeting and have an adventure. The boy also tries to get magic by kidnapping a bad witch, but then bad magic gets in his blood.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like Cressida Cowell's "The Wizards of Once".

[Google Books description](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Wizards_of_Once.html?id=WG5FDgAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)

> Once there were Wizards, who were Magic, and Warriors, who were not. But Xar, son of the King of Wizards, can't cast a single spell. And Wish, daughter of the Warrior Queen, has a banned magical object of her own. When they collide in the wildwood, on the trail of a deadly witch, it's the start of a grand adventure that just might change the fabric of their worlds.